# Swap some labels in legend - matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

Consider the following example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


fig = plt.figure(figsize=(4,6))
axis = fig.add_subplot(111)
x = np.linspace(1,2,100)
axis.plot(x, x, label = "a")
axis.plot(x, x**2, label = "b")
axis.plot(x, x**3, label = "c")
axis.plot(x, x**4, label = "d")
axis.legend()

plt.show()
```

Is there a simple way to swap the first (a with blue line) and last object (d with red line) with each other without changing the order in the code. The legend should therefore show the order (from top to bottom):

- red line d
- orange line b
- green line c
- blue handling a

Comment: You can mention the color of the plot also in the `plot()` function. 
`axis.plot(x, x, '#0f0f0f', label="a")` in this case, the hex color code has been used to choose the color. For more options you can check https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/colors/colors.html

Comment: I probably said it wrong. I want to swap the first and last object ( = colored line + text) in the legend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get the legend's handles and labels with [`get_legend_handles_labels`](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.get_legend_handles_labels.html) and reset them in the mentioned order:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16,10))
axis = fig.add_subplot(111)
x = np.linspace(1,2,100)
axis.plot(x, x, label = "a")
axis.plot(x, x**2, label = "b")
axis.plot(x, x**3, label = "c")
axis.plot(x, x**4, label = "d")

axis.legend()
handles, labels = axis.get_legend_handles_labels()
axis.legend([handles[-1]] + handles[1:-1] + [handles[0]], 
            [labels[-1]] + labels[1:-1] + [labels[0]])

plt.show()
```

[image]